# Error: Missing data in columns: pop when running random forest regression using the ranger package

Tags: r, random-forest, raster, na

I am trying to implement random forest (RF) regression using the `ranger` package in `R`, but I am getting this error: `Error: Missing data in columns: pop` (*pop* is my independent variable) when running the `predict` function.

For reference, when using the `randomForest` package, I can use the `na.action = na.omit` function to exclude the *NA* values, but in `ranger` I can't do this.

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")) [[1:2]] 
names(s) = c("ntl", "covar")
s[10:20, ] <- NA
 
library(ranger)
m <- ranger(ntl~., data=as.data.frame(s, na.rm=TRUE), mtry=1)
p <- predict(s, m)
#Error: Missing data in columns: covar.
#In addition: Warning message:
#In lapply(r, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: does data = as.data.frame(s) creates a data frame ? check with summary(s) and str(s)

Comment: Yes, it does. Essentially, it is a `data.frame` with two columns containing the pixel values of my raster layers.

Comment: Then try to add these lines of code before the line m <- ranger.... :     s <- as.data.frame(s) ; s[is.na(s$pop)==F,]. And in the m <- ranger... just write data = s.

Comment: `s <- as.data.frame(s) ; s[is.na(s$pop)==F,]` gives me the same error, i.e., `Error: Missing data in columns: pop`. If I do `s = as.data.frame(s)` and then `s = na.omit(s)` and I run the `predict` function I am getting this error: `Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "data.frame"`. There is a workaround but it requires to add few extra lines of code, which I think it's unnecessary. There should be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `na.rm=TRUE`

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.53
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")) [[1:2]] 
names(s) = c("ntl", "covar")
s[10:20, ] <- NA

library(ranger)
m <- ranger(ntl~., data=as.data.frame(s, na.rm=TRUE), mtry=1)
p <- predict(s, m, na.rm=TRUE)

p
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        :  prediction 
#min value   :   0.2525767 
#max value   : 254.6400884
```